# Reconstruction Error in PCA

Tags: pca

I've read that if we have a data matrix $X$ and the eigenvectors $V$ of its covariance matrix $Cov(X) = X^{T}X$, then whereas $$XV$$ gives us the projection of our data on low dimension, $$XVV^{T}$$ should give us a **reconstruction** ($\hat{X}$) of our original data matrix.

$X$ projected onto $V$ is easy to visualize, but what is the meaning of $X$ projected onto $VV^{T}$?

I've read nearly every post by @amoeba on PCA in my bid to better understand it and I found [this post particularly helpful](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GNgt.png). But what I can't seem to wrap my head around is, how can I visually illustrate that the projection $XV$ projected on $V^{T}$ (or $X$ projected on $VV^{T}$, which ever interpretation is correct) is the reconstruction? Below, I only consider one eigenvector (k = 1). Is my interpretation drawn below correct..? What is the geometric interpretation of projecting onto the transpose of an eigenvector ($V^{T}$)?

[image: PCA Reconstruction]